# Can I check multiple ancestors in JavaScript using Element.closest()?

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a verbose condition:

```
if (
    (e.target.parentNode.classList[0] === 'my-class') ||
    (e.target.parentNode.parentNode.classList[0] === 'my-class') ||
    (e.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.classList[0] === 'my-class')
) {

/* [... CODE HERE...] */

}
```

In some contexts, I can easily imagine the condition extending to 5 lines or more.

I am aware that I can write a recursive function which checks if the next higher-up ancestor node is not `<body>` and, if not, runs the same recursive function on that node.

But given that `Element.closest()` exists:

**See:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest

is there a simpler way I can write the condition, something along the lines of:

```
if (e.target.closest('.my-class') !== false) {

/* [... CODE HERE...] */

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the summary:

> If there isn't such an ancestor, it returns `null`.

So:

```
if (e.target.closest('.my-class') !== null)
```

In the event that `e.target` itself may be a `.my-class`, and you want to exclude that, you need to start from the element's parent:

```
if (e.target.parentNode.closest('.my-class') !== null)
```

but if `e.target` is guaranteed never to be a `.my-class` the first example will suffice.